# Singleton design pattern

Tags: design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are singletons handled in a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391191/how-are-singletons-handled-in-a-web-application)

Is singleton design pattern creates single instance for JVM or single instance for an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this [SO thread useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391191/how-are-singletons-handled-in-a-web-application).

Answer (score 2):

It's a single instance per running application

Comment: -1, this is wrong. The term application is not defined inside of a JVM.

Comment: It's not. I answered using the same term as the OP. It doesn't really matter if the term is defined in JVM or not as long as the OP knows what he means. Remember that the answers if made specifically for the asked question and not for everyone in general. And the difference between `creates single instance for JVM` and `single instance for an application` is quite large.

Comment: It is nevertheless wrong and your clarification here makes no sense either. A singleton is a one object only instance per CLASSLOADER not per Application (what ever that is) or per JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton design pattern is typically implemented at the class level, though it could be implemented at the application level. I believe there is only ever one JVM instance running at a time.

Comment: I daresay one per class loader then. Two separate class loaders may load the same class.

Comment: I have always implemented my singleton classes with static loaders, which determine if an instance has been given, so what you say is true; though the way I've implemented it makes them one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear. What is an "application"?

Programs like Word or Excel are applications, also an Apache web server is one.

If you have some programs that are implemented in Java, usually each of them is starting its own JVM ... **emphasize on usually**

You can easy find ways to run several applications inside the same JVM. E.g. this is done in "application servers" or "web servers"/servlet containers.

As someone above pointed out: you will have one singleton per *Class Loader*.

In an application server/app container/web container every "application" gets its own class laoder asigned. So you have one singleton per Application (because of its Class Loader).

If you have only one application on your JVM or only one Class Loader you obviously only have one singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Its one singleton instance for one running instance of the application. Each running instance of your application will get its own JVM though. So, effectively, each JVM has its own instance of your singleton.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of Singleton based on creation a class with a method(or property in .NET) that creates an instance of this class if one doesn't exists yet. The constructor of class must be private to prevent other ways of initialization.

For more details I recommand you to read this [article.](http://zuta-developer.blogspot.com/2012/06/singleton-pattern.html)